# EF Core Error - SqlException: Invalid object name 'Grape'

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I get the following errors regarding 2 classes.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SqlException: Invalid object name 'Grape'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__164_0(Task
> result)

and

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SqlException: Invalid object name 'Supplier'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__164_0(Task
> result)

There are 2 classes that I cannot add to the database for no reason.

I've already had them and one of them could make CRUD opperations. I was properly working. I dropped one migration and once I added another clean one, those 2 specific classes decided to disappear from the database.

I thought that there could be a connection error, but no because I can still make transactions and add other classes. I added the test class for testing.

Here is my database:

```
public class DB : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    // Wines
    public DbSet<WineBrand> WineBrands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WineType> WineTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Harvest> Harvests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Deposit> Deposits { get; set; }

    // Grapes
    public DbSet<Grape> Grapes { get; set; }

    // Orders
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderStatus> OrderStatus { get; set; }

    // News
    public DbSet<NewsCategory> NewsCategories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewsItem> NewsItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NewsType> NewsTypes { get; set; }

    // Logistics
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }

    // test
    public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
}
```

Both classes have Services, which are both added to the Startup. They both have Controllers and Views.

Can anyone help me, please?

I would appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Can anyone help me, please?" - Yes. Ask a question as per site rules with minimum source code to produce the error. Do not expect us to guess what you do not know how to show us. We answer technical questions. We do not replace your need to do some basic debugging yourself.

Comment: Thanks in advance for being so rude. Not all of us knows the proper way to do it. Not all of us start coding in a high level. That's why we learn. Instead of being so rude and criticizing, you should instead be a bit more humble and explain or keep it for yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the migration that you dropped has been removed in the code and database.

After, As the 2 tables disappeared from the database, you could try add a new migration.

Comment: You're a life saver. Didn't delete also from the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the table name matches the name of the class if not you could match the names or use the DataAnnotation attribute for mapping the table name as below. Schema property is used if you have used schema for the tables.

```
[Table("StudentMaster", Scheme = "SchemaName")]
public class Student
{
   public int StudentID { get; set; }
   public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wellington Júnior answered my question. Thanks anyway! Good job